# BigCommerce orders API: paginated retrieval with filtering (modified_date, order status)

Tags: api, pagination, filtering, bigcommerce, orders

Podbox is building a connector using the [BigCommerce orders API](http://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/api/v2/resources/orders) to synchronize orders from a BigCommerce e-store to cloud CRMs (like vTiger, Salesforce or ZohoCRM). As one of the developers, I found that there are unfortunately a couple of points that prevent the process from being efficient:

- it would be great to have a paginated retrieval, with *page* and *limit* parameters, as in the [customers API](http://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/api/v2/resources/customers). That would reduce the workload for both the BigCommerce server and the client server
- both customers and orders API calls return the *date modified* field and it would be great to use them as filters to retrieve the orders that were updated after a given date. With such criteria, the data returned by the API calls would be small, saving bandwidth and reducing workload for both BigCommerce and client servers too
- another optimization would be to use the *status id* criteria as a filter in order to retrieve only the uncomplete orders, but it seems that this criteria in only usable in the form of "*status id* equals [value]", I would like to use it in the form "*status id* differs from 7" (7 being the *status id* of a complete order) but it does not seem currently feasible to me

Would these feature requests be useful to other developers? Do some BigCommerce developers know whether these feature requests are on the road map? Or if I should propose them somewhere else?

Thanks anyway for your attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 out of 3 request by you has already been implemented by BigCommerce.

- [page and limit parameters](http://developer.bigcommerce.com/quickstarts/php#Get.all.orders.from.the.store)
- You can pull modified orders by passing an 'If-Modified-Since' header. This will only return items that have been modified since the provided RFC-2822 date.

No idea about the status code issue, But i found [this](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/api/v2/resources/order_statuses#get-orderstatusesidjson), I guess setting `status_id` filter as `0`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you @chirag-b for your answers. It's a shame that BigCommerce mentioned the page + limit parameters directly in the [customers API](http://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/api/v2/resources/customers) and in the quickstarts and not in the "official" orders documentation page. Same for 'If-Modified-Since' (which is mentioned as the creation date, not an edition date in the quickstarts)

For the status, my criteria would be `status_id <> 7`, which is different from `status_id == 0`

Help pages are hard to maintain :) Thanks again!